# Is there a bug with "set chained" in setAutoCommit() in net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, sybase, jtds

I am having some confusion with `set chained` statement in `setAutoCommit()` method in `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`

The [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.2.2/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/ConnectionJDBC2.java) says:

```
2161  if (serverType == Driver.SYBASE) {
2162            if (autoCommit) {
2163                sql.append("SET CHAINED OFF");
2164            } else {
2165                sql.append("SET CHAINED ON");
2166            }
```

However, **shouldn't it be backwards, and chaining should be OFF for autoCommit==false?**

---

The reason I ran into this is as follows:

I am writing a Java app which needs to do some complicated SQL and roll back all of it if any of it fails:

- Open Sybase connection using `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`
- Call setAutoCommit(false)
- Do SQL1
- Call stored proc 'MySP1'

  - Stored proc MySP1' is NOT under my control
  - It has `EXEC sp_procxmode 'dbo.MySP1','unchained'`
- Do SQL2
- If SQL2 fails, roll back everything (including SQL1), otherwise commit.

Having done that, I get the following error from MySP1:

```
 Stored procedure 'MySP1' may be run only in unchained transaction mode. The 'SET CHAINED OFF' command will cause the current session to use unchained transaction mode.
```

Comment: have you tried the steps in [here](http://osdir.com/ml/java.ibatisdb.user/2005-01/msg00007.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same problem and solved it by running following SQL. hopefully it can help you.

```
sp_procxmode your_stored_Procedure, 'anymode'
```

in your case **your_stored_Procedure = MySP1** then you should run following code:

```
 sp_procxmode MySP1, 'anymode'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody looks here after long 7 years,

I've made it work by

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false); // this is mandatory, as without it jTDS will commit each statement.
```

in java, and explicitly executing SQL code:

```
SET CHAINED OFF
begin transaction
```