# How can I resolve "Stored procedure 'MySP1' may be run only in unchained transaction mode" error?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, sybase, jtds

I am writing a Java app which needs to do some complicated SQL and roll back all of it if any of it fails:

- Open Sybase connection using `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`
- Call setAutoCommit(false)
- Do SQL1
- Call stored proc 'MySP1'

  - Stored proc MySP1' is NOT under my control
  - It has `EXEC sp_procxmode 'dbo.MySP1','unchained'`
- Do SQL2
- If SQL2 fails, roll back everything (including SQL1), otherwise commit.

Having done that, I get the following error from MySP1:

> **Stored procedure 'MySP1' may be run only in unchained transaction mode. The '`SET CHAINED OFF`' command will cause the current session to use unchained transaction mode.**

---

I have tried the following, all of which didn't help:

1. Add "chained=false" to the Properties object passed to `getConnection()` method ([advice source](http://www.inetsoftware.de/documentation/jdbc-driver/other-dbms/sybase/manual.html)).

   This had no effect, most likely because it seems to me that `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` does **not** support `chained` property.
2. Add "chained=false" to the URL string passed to `getConnection()` method ([advice source](http://www.inetsoftware.de/documentation/jdbc-driver/other-dbms/sybase/manual.html)).

   This had no effect as well
3. Called `SET CHAINED OFF` SQL after `setAutoCommit()`:

   ```
     PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SET CHAINED OFF");
     st.execute();
   ```

   This had no effect.
4. Investigated how `setAutoCommit()` works

   This has led me to believe that there may be a [bug in the driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964365/is-there-a-bug-with-set-chained-in-setautocommit-in-net-sourceforge-jtds-jdb). However, #1-#3 should have worked around the bug if that's the case
5. Called `setAutoCommit(true)` instead of `setAutoCommit(false)`.

   this fixed the error about unchained mode, but as far as I understand, it means that I can NOT roll back 100% of my SQL at the end, since the first SQL statements would already be autocommitted by that time.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that jdbc's "Autocommit" is the same thing as Sybase chained mode.

Autocommit true means commit after each statement - that's unchained: the transactions are not all in one "chain" that can be committed and rolled back as one.

So you might be stuck.  If you cannot change that SP then it's always going to turn off chained mode.  You are getting a reasonable message.  Is it actually an error message, or is it just that your jdbc code does not handle it (i.e. display it or don't display it, but at least treat it as not an error?)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody looks here after all these years.

I've stumbled upon the same case. 
You were very close with way  3. 
but in this case jTDS doesn't start a tran (But is is mandatory in Unchained mode). You can do it manually by executing

```
begin transaction
```

just after running

```
SET CHAINED OFF
```

Comment: for alternative jConnect driver:

the similar situation is resolved by setting SERVER_INITIATED_TRANSACTIONS=false to connection string